# How many divisors of $8!$ divide exactly in $2$ numbers from $\{6,10,12,21\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to check how many divisors of $8!$ divide exactly in $2$ numbers from $\{6,10,12,21\}$
first I tried to write $8!$ as $8\cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 2^3 \cdot 7 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 2^7 \cdot 7 \cdot 5\cdot 3^2 \cdot 1$
how should I continue ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all of 6, 10, 12 and 21 divide $8!$, the "divisors of $8!$" is a red herring, and you're actually looking just for how many (natural) numbers divide exactly two of 6, 10, 12, 21.

You can either try all combinations such as "divides 6 and 12 but not 10 or 21" -- there are 6 of them to try -- or draw a Hasse diagram of the divisibility relations for numbers that are divisors of at least one of the numbers and try to work it out by eye.

But simply trying every number up to 12 is probably quicker than either of these. (Since 12 is the second largest of the given numbers, no number larger than that can be a divisor of *two* of them).

Comment: I dont know how to continue.., I know that I have 96 divisors for $8!$ how its help me?